# How to get URL of a folder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a folder named `uploads` which is on same level as of `app` folder. How can I use a Laravel helper like `URL::to` to get the file path in it?

Comment: You can't. Only folders in the `public` directory are accessible by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the comments above are true (*the files are not directly accessible by the browser*) - you can still provide link access to these files through a function.

The trick is to use php function [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

This allows you to then secure the files, and apply permissions to them - i.e. only certain users can access the files, users can only access their own files etc.

This is an example of one way you can allow a logged in user to access a file

A route like this:

```
Route::get('/view/{$file}', ['as' => 'viewfile', function($file) {
     // Ensure no funny business names to prevent directory transversal etc.
     $file = str_replace ('..', '', $file);
     $file = str_replace ('/', '', $file);

     // now do the logic to check user is logged in
     if (Auth::check())
     {
            // Serve file via readfile() - we hard code the user_ID - so they
            // can only get to their own files
           readfile('../uploads/'.Auth::user()->id.'/'.$file);
     }
}]);
```

Then in a view file somewhere you can link to the file like this:

```
<p>Here is a link to your file: {{ URL::route('viewfile', ['your_file_name.jpg']) }}</p>
```

Comment: @Volatil3 - did this solve your problem? Or do you need more info?

Comment: Hey it seems you understand these things. My question is: how can I make a certain user to have permission to access a user's file. Let's say user_1 has files: file1,file2,file3 and user_2 can access only perticular file or have no access to non of them?